# Turn flat array into 2D array taking equally sized chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a [freecodecamp](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-chunky-monkey?solution=function%20chunk%28arr%2C%20size%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Break%20it%20up.%0A%20%20var%20output%20%3D%20[]%3B%0A%20%20for%28var%20x%3D0%3B%20x%3Carr.length%3B%20x%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%28arr.length%20%3E%3D%20size%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20output.push%28arr.splice%28[0]%2C%20size%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20output.push%28arr.splice%28[0]%2C%20arr.length%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20output%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Achunk%28[%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22c%22%2C%20%22d%22]%2C%202%29%3B%0A) exercise, and need helping figuring out why my code is not working as intended. So the purpose of this exercise is to:

> Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the
>   length of size (second argument) and returns them as a
>   multidimensional array.

Why doesn't this code return `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]`?

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var output = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    if (arr.length >= size) {
      output.push(arr.splice([0], size));
    } else {
      output.push(arr.splice([0], arr.length));
    }
  }
  return output;
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(
  chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
));
```

Comment: Have a look at splice's definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `for` loop with a much simpler `while` loop:

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var output = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    if (arr.length >= size) {
      output.push(arr.splice(0, size));
    } else {
      output.push(arr.splice(0, arr.length));
    }
  }
  return output;
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(
  chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
));
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first argument to splice be an integer to represent the start of the splice `arr.splice(0,size)` ? What is the meaning of `(arr.splice([0], size)` ?

Comment: @Danield, indeed. Just copied-and-pasted the original, and it seems to work with `[0]` even though that's not quite correct. Fixed.

Comment: Interesting that [0] as the argument actually works! +1 I learnt something new!

Answer (score 1):

`arr.splice` also modifies `arr`. This way, in your example, after the first call of `arr.splice(0, size)` (note its not `[0]`), `arr` only has 4 elements, and after the second call, there are only 2 elements left. Therefore `x < arr.legnth` gets earlier true than you want it to be.

Another issue is that you only increase `x` by 1 in each iteration, where it should be `size`.

overall, this should work

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var output = []; 
  var l = arr.length;
  for (var x = 0; x < l; x+=size) {                                                      
    if (arr.length >= size) {
      output.push(arr.splice(0, size));
    } else {
      output.push(arr.splice(0, arr.length));
    }   
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
```

Comment: You can just replace `var l = arr.length; for (var x = 0; x < l; x+=size) { ... }` with `for (; 0 < arr.length;) { ... }`. You don't even need `x`.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way with modulo.

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
  for (var x = 0, l = arr.length, arrD = []; x < l; x++) {
    x % size === 0 ? arrD.push([arr[x]]) : arrD[arrD.length - 1].push(arr[x]);
  }
  return arrD;
}

var _ = chunk(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);

document.write(JSON.stringify(_));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var output = [];
  var length = arr.length/size; // this is because each time you splice original array size reduces.
  for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    if (arr.length > size) {
      output.push(arr.splice([0], size));
    } else {
      output.push(arr.splice([0], arr.length));
    }
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
```

Comment: You can just replace `var length = arr.length/size; for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) { ... }` with `for (; 0 < arr.length;) { ... }`. You don't even need `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't working because by using `splice`, you remove items from the array during the iteration, but you don't change the loop variable (`x`) accordingly.

A possible solution could be changing the `for loop` to `while`:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var output = [];
  while(arr.length > 0) {
    if (arr.length >= size) {
      output.push(arr.splice([0], size));
    } else {
      output.push(arr.splice([0], arr.length));
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `while(arr.length > 0) { ... }`, you could also just do `for(;arr.length > 0;) { ... }`. The behavior of both statements is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var output = [];
  var yo = arr.length;
  for (var x = 0; x < yo; x++) {
    if (arr.length > size) {
      output.push(arr.splice([0], size));
    } else {
      output.push(arr);
      break;
    }
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
```

The issues were:

1. Array length was always changing as `splice` modifies the array itself.
2. `arr.length > size` should be the condition.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/k8wr0yqa/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var i, temparray, finalarray = [];
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
    temparray = arr.slice(i, i+size);
    finalarray.push(temparray);
  }

  return finalarray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

`splice` deletes elements from your array. Because of that, your array will automatically get smaller and smaller until no more elements are left.

This means your loop should stop when `0 < arr.length` and only then. This also means you can completely remove your `x` variable.

#### Demo :

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
    // Break it up.
    var output = [];
    for (; 0 < arr.length;) {
        if (arr.length >= size) {
            output.push(arr.splice(0, size));
        } else {
            output.push(arr.splice(0, arr.length));
        }
    }
    return output;
}

var data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'];

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' +
                          'SIZE 3\n-------\n' +
                          JSON.stringify(chunk(data, 3), null, 2) +
                          '</pre>';
```

---

## An alternative approach

It's better not to use `splice`, because it deletes all the data from your array. This means you can't eg. execute `chunk` twice or do anything else with your array after executing `chunk`.

A better approach, would be to use `slice` instead, which just copies a segment of your array and leaves the array intact.

Using `slice`, you can just use a classic for-loop, except that you increment isn't `1` but the `size` of your segments.

#### Demo :

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
    var output = [];
    var length = arr.length;
    for (var x = 0, length = arr.length; x < length; x = x + size) {
        output.push(arr.slice([x], x + size));
    }
    return output;
}

var data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'];

document.body.innerHTML = 
                          '<pre>' +
                          'SIZE 2\n-------\n' +
                          JSON.stringify(chunk(data, 2), null, 2) +
                          "\n\n"+
                          'SIZE 3\n-------\n' +
                          JSON.stringify(chunk(data, 3), null, 2) +
                          "\n\n"+
                          'SIZE 4\n-------\n' +
                          JSON.stringify(chunk(data, 4), null, 2)  +
                          "\n\n"+
                          'SIZE 5\n-------\n' +
                          JSON.stringify(chunk(data, 5), null, 2)  +
                          "\n\n"+
                          'SIZE 6\n-------\n' +
                          JSON.stringify(chunk(data, 6), null, 2)  +
                          "\n\n"+
                          'SIZE 7\n-------\n' +
                          JSON.stringify(chunk(data, 7), null, 2) +
                          '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "one-liner" using recursion:

```js
function chunk(a, s) {
  return a.length ? [a.slice(0, s)].concat(chunk(a.slice(s), s)) : [];
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(
    chunk(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2)
));
```